# Vector bundle with Euclidean metric isomorphic to dual

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, geometric-topology

I am trying to proof, that if a vector bundle $\xi$ posses an Euclidean metric, then it is isomorphic to its dual $Hom( \xi, \epsilon^1 )$, where $\epsilon^1 = B( \xi ) \times \mathbb{R}$ denotes the trivial line bundle.

This statement suprises me, as locally the statement should always hold. Does someone have a counterexample of a vector bundle, where this is not true?

My "proof" so far is the following:

Consider the map $\Phi: E(\xi) \to Hom(\xi, \epsilon^1)$, that maps $y=(x,b) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times F$ after the choice of a neighborhood to $g_b(x, -)$, where $g_b(-,-)$ is the metric at the basepoint $b$.
It is an isomorphism as $g_b$ is positive definite, so its describing matrix (after the choice of a basis) is invertible, so any linear form  $\varphi \in (E(\xi)_b)^*$ is of the form $g_b(z,-)$ of the form $g_b(z,-)$.

I feel uncomfortable with it, as for me it is not clear, if everything glues to a global map, as I only consider everything locally, by using the isomorphism $(x,b) \in U \cong \mathbb{R}^n \times F$. Is it true, that these map glue to a global map, and how can one show this?

Comment: The key is that the metric $g$ is assumed to be globally defined, so you can simply glue your local isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct; you do not even need a Euclidean metric, any (fiberwise) nondegenerate continuous bilinear form $\omega$ will suffice. To construct an isomorphism $\xi\to \xi^*$ use the fiberwise isomorphism
$$
\xi_b\to \xi^*_b, v\mapsto \omega(v, \cdot).
$$ 
It is clear that this map is well-defined. To check its continuity, use local trivialization, where the bundle is the product
$$
U\times F,
$$ 
where $F$ is the fiber. With respect to this product structure, $\omega$ has the form
$$
\omega_b(\cdot, \cdot)
$$
where  $b\mapsto \omega_b$ is a continuous map from the base $U$ to the space of 2-tensors on the fiber $F$. Now, continuity of the map 
$$
(v,b)\mapsto \omega_b(v, \cdot)
$$
is clear.

Comment: For me it is not clear, that the map is well-defined.How do I know, that for a point $v \in E(\xi)$ the linear form $\omega_b(v, \cdot)$ is independent of the choice of the local trivialization? So if $v$ is an element of two different "trivial covers", depending on it, it might be written as $(b,v)$ or $(b,w)$, so the linear forms could be different?

Comment: @Matthias: The form $\omega_b$ is well-defined (independent of a trivialization), hence, $\omega_b(v,\cdot)$ is well-defined as well. If you want to know why there is a nondegenerate continuous bilinear form $\omega$, that's a different question.